# Bootstrap new panel color set

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a new panel style. Basically I would change only the background and border color the rest based on the default color scheme. I do not want to overwrite the default one. How should I do that?

Something like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default newstyle-panel"> .... </div>
<style>
    .newstyle-panel { color #333; background-color: #e2b500; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@panel-bg` is responsible for panel background.

Text color comes from `@gray-dark`, you cannot change it for panel only without affecting the rest of components. So you also will need to edit the compiled CSS and add custom panel text color there.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe my explanation was wrong. I can not create the CSS part. I've found the names in the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ Panel section but I do not know how to use them. E.g. to overwrite the background color.